# How to search for a file and then use the file in a loop

Tags: python, path

i'm trying to make a script that has to open a file that i give in the argument's (sys.argv[1]) of the script and print the lines in it. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
import sys

path="/home/st/citys/"'{0}'"/"'{1}'"/street/house/"'{2}' .format(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[1])    

with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile:
  for line in infile:
    print(line.split()[1])
```

besides that the path of the file changes for every different sys.argv[1] that i will give running the script so i was wandering if there's any module that can help me whit that problem

Comment: Are you sending the full-path ?

Comment: yes i'm sending the full path

Comment: Try to hardcode the path into the "open" statement. Does it work ? if not, the path is wrong, if it's working, print `path` to make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: What does _it doesn't work_ mean? What output/error do you get?

Comment: Also, you're wrapping `format()` placeholders in double quotes, so your path becomes `/home/st/citys/'argument1'/'argument2'/street/house/'argument3'`